# What is the difference between tiles:insert and tiles:get in tiles framework?

Tags: java, struts2, struts, tiles

I want to use tiles in Struts2 framework.
What is basic difference between tiles:insert and tiles:get as both the tag used for displaying tiles content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<tiles:insert attribute="header" ignore="true"> is equivalent to <tiles:get attribute="header" >`

The ignore attribute, if true, means ignore the attribute if missing. Otherwise, If ignore is false, the tiles framework will throw an exception and the page will not display if the parameter does not pass.  Default value is false in case of "tiles:insert".